# Lock Drawing Mode VSTO 4.0

Tags: excel, vsto, office-interop, vba

i am working on an Excel AddIn Development using Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO 4.0). 
there is an option in Excel [Lock Drawing mode](http://blog.contextures.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/LockDrawing.gif) for specific shape which enable a user to draw a shape multiple times.

my requirement is to enable "Lock Drawing mode" (for ElbowConnector) using C#/VB.Net using VSTO 4.0. 
 i tried to find a solution to this even in VBA but did not get any luck.

Thank you,

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute the built-in button programmatically. The ExecuteMso method of the CommandBars class allows to run the built-in controls programmatically. See [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798).

Comment: infact i am using it already. but i could not identify which one can i use to enable Lock Drawing Mode functionality.
can u please identify for me? 
right now i have implemented it using Shapes custom events.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSExcelNewEventForShapes-0e26b1f2/sourcecode?fileId=73122&pathId=816504209

 after creating a connector i check for a boolean varialble and re-execute the MSO function untill the user presses escape.